# Not landing in Home page when I login as a User

Tags: home-page-component

I am the system admin for the org, when I login as a specific user, after going to his user record, it always takes me to the below page .. "Welcome to salesforce" but i am expecting me to take to his Home page.

Whereas if i login with a different user with the same profile and role it is taking me to the home pages of the user.. Could anyone please suggest whats going on here....How do i make it to take me to the Home page..

https://.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=&ic=1

```
![Home page is wrong][1]
```

Comment: What's the user's profile? What type of license is it?

Comment: It is a custom profile and Salesforce license..(full user license)